# Unir colunas numa só coluna SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu tenho três colunas, pertencentes á mesma tabela na base de dados, sendo estes:
Crescimento, Autonomia Financeira e RacioLiquidez;
Todos as colunas são do tipo bit.

O que eu necessito é agrupar os três campos numa só coluna, ou seja, se eu fizer:

```
SELECT IsNull(Crescimento,0) As Crescimento,

IsNull(AutonomiaFinanceira,0) As AutonomiaFinanceira,

IsNull(RacioLiquidez,0) As RacioLiquidez

from Estado
```

Eu obtenho o seguinte:

[image: Tabela Obtida]

No entanto eu quero agrupar estes três campos numa só coluna, aparecendo por exemplo: 000 ou 0,0,0.

Comment: Qual seria o `SGDB`?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode usar o [`CONCAT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql):

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(
    IsNull(Crescimento,0),'-',
    IsNull(AutonomiaFinanceira,0),'-',
    IsNull(RacioLiquidez,0)
  )
from Estado;
```

Veja um exemplo funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1511c/2).

Observação: A syntax do `CONCAT` é diferente entre os `SGDBs`.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado :)